# Generating Custom GitSCM Changelog in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins (2.36) pipeline job, where I check out a git project and I want to control what goes into the changelog:

```
CHANGELOG = ""
CHECK_SINCE = 1488326400

stage('Fetch') {
    node('docker') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace'], [$class: 'AuthorInChangelog']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '...', url: '...']]])
        CHANGELOG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log --after ${CHECK_SINCE} --pretty=fommit %H %ntree %T %nparent %P %nauthor %an <%ae> %ad %ncommiter %cn <%ce> %cd %n %n    %s %n %n %n' --raw --no-abbrev").trim()
        docker.build("pipeline_test", "tools/build").inside {
            sh 'echo HELLO!'
        }
    }
}

stage('Update') {
    node('master') {
        fileExists "${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/PipelineTest/jobs/${JOB_BASE_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_ID}/changelog0.xml"
        changelog_file = new File("${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/PipelineTest/jobs/${JOB_BASE_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_ID}/changelog0.xml")
        changelog_file << CHANGELOG
    }
}
```

When I view the file `changelog0.xml`, the content is exactly as it should be:

```
commit b2f615ee31bc51922cdd6ca373a90b70d5c95d1b
tree 9bd57df4c9c85ee1958d7e5b3ba3ab999e18e752
parent 35c47eb0b3a0cb77574465a8136ad37a294f45ca
author ssengupta <ssengupta@gmail.com> 2017-03-10 12:53:41 +0100
committer ssengupta <ssengupta@gmail.com> 2017-03-10 12:53:41 +0100

    Some more changes.



:100644 100644 1ac06d64c274f8e2dbea325a07c15f11d2f5b4d0 6460796ab551fc1b84d25ebadbd369187fdec382 M  ReadMe.md
commit 35c47eb0b3a0cb77574465a8136ad37a294f45ca
tree 7a5cdb20288c4f3504117cfede5451e3b94fc465
parent 5b6d2f65010c0ae758c002d7a7eb0e66677c3193
author ssengupta <ssengupta@gmail.com> 2017-03-10 12:53:26 +0100
committer ssengupta <ssengupta@gmail.com> 2017-03-10 12:53:26 +0100

    Some changes



:100644 100644 dd7dbfe9ab082d444c9510f00fc79d7f72121012 1ac06d64c274f8e2dbea325a07c15f11d2f5b4d0 M  ReadMe.md
```

But when I want to view the changelog from my Jenkins web frontend's job page by clicking on the 'Changes' link from the left menu, the changelog is visible there if and only if I remove the `docker.build().inside{}` block. Otherwise it is empty.

I have tried setting a unique image name for every build. I have tried introducing delays in various places. Does not help.

What is changing that is making the changelog show up empty in the web frontend? How do I fix it?

## Update

I have also tried a different approach: updating `currentBuild.changeSets` instead of writing to `changelog0.xml`. The pipeline script the looks like this:

```
import hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet

CHANGELOG = ""
CHECK_SINCE = 1488326400

stage('Fetch') {
    node('docker') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace'], [$class: 'AuthorInChangelog']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '...', url: '...']]])
        CHANGELOG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log --after ${CHECK_SINCE} --pretty=fommit %H %ntree %T %nparent %P %nauthor %an <%ae> %ad %ncommiter %cn <%ce> %cd %n %n    %s %n %n %n' --raw --no-abbrev").trim()
        docker.build("pipeline_test", "tools/build").inside {
            sh 'echo HELLO!'
        }
        def modified_changes = new GitChangeSet(CHANGELOG.readLines(), true)
        currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets << modified_changes
    }
}
```

Although I am not a Java developer, I expected the above code to do something meaningful, since [GitChangeSet](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSet.java) has the constructor `public GitChangeSet(List<String> lines, boolean authorOrCommitter)`

The pipeline successfully executed. But when I clicked on the 'Changes' link on the web frontend, I got this:

```
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/workflow-job/WEB-INF/lib/workflow-job.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun/changes.jelly:33:67: <st:include> No page found 'index.jelly' for class hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:97)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.modernstatus.ModernStatusFilter.doFilter(ModernStatusFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.modernstatus.ModernStatusFilter.doFilter(ModernStatusFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why would you want the Changes information to be inaccurate? Jenkins automatically shows you the commits since the last build already. Also, you can't write a plaintext git log to an internal Jenkins XML file. Anyway, the Docker Build plugin does some fingerprinting, but I'm not aware of a reason why it would alter the Changes.

Comment: It is totally possible that whoever monitors the pipeline wants to see changes since the last nightly build and not just the last successful build. It is possible that during the build process, some external dependency manager like 'gitman' or 'bower' is invoked, and the user wants to see changes from the submodules thus updated in the same changelog. Whether it is inaccurate or not depends on what the user wants, right?

Comment: That suggests a bit of a weird job setup to me, but yeah, you could do it — again I think adding your own changesets to the build may be the best way.

Comment: Instead of syntax `currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets << modified_changes` you should use `currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets.add()` or `currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets.push()`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't really understand your question, but using the Java `File` API is not supported in Pipeline — it will not behave as you expect.

You really should avoid writing directly into the `$JENKINS_HOME` directory as well — write a file to the build workspace, then use the `archiveArtifacts` step to ensure that it gets stored on the Jenkins master.

You can do this using the [`writeFile` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-writefile-code-write-file-to-workspace), e.g.:

```java
def changelog = sh returnStdout: true, script: "git log …"
writeFile file: 'changelog0.xml', text: changelog
archiveArtifacts 'changelog0.xml'
```

Note also that you should run both the `checkout` and the `git log` steps in the same `node('docker')` block (they can still be in separate `stage` blocks though, inside the `node`).  Otherwise, it's not guaranteed that you'll get the same workspace in both cases, and so when you call `git log`, you may end up in an empty or outdated workspace.

Comment: After re-reading my question, it does sound misleading. I have edited it. Could you please have another look? Writing into the `changelog0.xml` is always successful and when I log in to Jenkins master and look at the file, the content is always the same. So the question is, why is Jenkins showing changes in the Job changelog (in the web frontend) when I remove the docker container call and not otherwise? `changelog0.xml` is a part of the build structure according to the Jenkins documentation. Do I have to explicitly archive it?

Comment: Your question makes some more sense now, but my advice here still applies :) The docs might refer to changelog.xml under the builds folder, but you should not write this file yourself. Especially not with plaintext.. it should be XML. There's no way of archiving a file to have it show up in Changes. You could however potentially use the Jenkins API to add a Changeset object to the `currentBuild.rawBuild` object.

Comment: When the GitSCM plugin builds the changelog itself, that is not XML either. It calls `git whatchanged` with some formatting arguments and dumps the result there. At least this is true for 3.0.1. I have read the changelog of the plugin development since, there I do not see it mentioned somewhere that they have switched to XML.

Comment: It seems to be a rather complex process to populate the `currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets` by iterating over the results of `git log` myself. There must be a parse method somewhere. But I do not find any examples of it being used.

Comment: Sorry, you're indeed correct. I'm surprised that the changelog is (apparently) parsed at display time — usually metadata like this is parsed into a data structure and serialised to XML. [`GitChangeSet`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSet.java) is the code that parses it.

Comment: I have updated my question. But I am not a Java developer and that could be causing certain misunderstandings. Could you please have another look? :)

Answer (score 3):

The following pipeline script should if all necessary script approvals are done add 1 commit to the changelog.

```
import hudson.scm.SubversionSCM
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser

node('master') {
  stage('build')
  {

  }
  stage('test') {
    writeFile file: 'changelog.xml', text: '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
  <logentry revision="12344">
    <author>me</author>
    <date>2017-12-21T16:57:06.737430Z</date>
    <paths>
      <path prop-mods="false" text-mods="true" kind="file" action="M">/path/to/repo/modified/file.cpp</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>my commit message</msg>
  </logentry>
</log>'''
    def parser = new SubversionChangeLogParser(false)
    def file = new File(env.WORKSPACE,"changelog.xml")
    def modified_changesets = parser.parse(currentBuild.rawBuild, null, file)
    currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets.add(modified_changesets)
  }
}
```

Comment: For Git, remove `import hudson.scm.SubversionSCM`, replace `import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser` with `hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeLogParser` and replace `new SubversionChangeLogParser` with `new GitChangeLogParser`. The following Git command seems to produce the correct output required by `GitChangeLogParser`: `git --no-pager log --raw --no-abbrev --format=raw`, despite that the format is not XML. You only have to add parameter to define desired revision range.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for similar solution and finally got this:-

Instead of updating your current variable **currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets**

Use this just before your checkout statement in pipeline/ pipeline library -

```
 currentBuild.getChangeSet().clear()
```

So once the currentChangeSet is cleared, it will fetch changes from your next git checkout which you can do using checkout() or git plugin syntax. It will also update changelog0.xml as per commits in the repository which you have specified in Pipeline and not repository in which Pipeline is hosted (in case you are developing [Pipeline Library](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) of your own)

Now you can further use it using $CHANGES variable as usual.